# How to remove failed test in Testng report on re rerunning the test case

Tags: java, testng, rest-assured

I am running 10 cases, every time some test fails due to environment instability, I have used iretry analyzer and resolved this issue by running my @test methods 3 times. Now the problem is in the testing reports am getting the failed as well passed results for the same test case, I want to remove the failed case which passed on rerun in the report

Detailed explanation:

```
Running test 1-5
TC1 - pass
TC2 - pass 
TC3 - fail
TC3 - pass (on retry using retry analyzer)
TC4 - Pass
TC5 - pass
```

The report is capturing test case TC3 2 times and at the end the report shows that this suite is a failure. How to overcome it?

Comment: why would you  want to remove this? you had to re-run it because it failed, if you remove it somehow, you'll not even be aware of this.

Comment: @Stultuske: yes i agree, but on the final run am getting both pass & fail for a test cases, i want my report to be customized as only pass should come if it has passed on re-run, else it can show fail